# Change text for CLLocationManager allow permission alert on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, cllocationmanager

I'm using CLLocationManager to retrieve user's location. The text of the alert reads:

> "AppName" would Like to Use Your Current Location" | "Don't Allow" | "Allow"

How, in OS X (Swift), can you change this text and/or where is "AppName" defined - it's not $(PRODUCT_NAME)

I know in iOS you can change the text in the Info.plist using following keys, but these make no change in OS X (10.11):

- NSLocationUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Comment: Bundle Display Name in Info.plist also doesnt come through. So Product Name (under Target > Build Settings > Packaging); Bundle Name, and Bundle Display Name have no effect. Cannot determine where the name is coming from (It's displaying the name I used on project creation which has been changed in all the above places)

Answer (score 1):

It uses the `Bundle name` property in the applications `Info.plist` file when displaying the alert

Comment: No, altering this has no effect. It grabs the name from some other location.

Comment: I am getting a hyphenated name which appears to be the final part of the Bundle Identifier. If I alter the Bundle Identifier in the plist file from $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) to anything else, this changes the  'AppName' in the alert text to match not the Bundle Name, but the Product Name in Build Settings. ?! Obviously, this is no solution - I need the Bundle Identifier.